# Problem with multivariable inequality

Tags: analysis, inequality

Basically I'm trying to prove a limit with the delta epsilon definition and I'm reading about how to do it. In one example, the book does the following:

$\lim_{(x,y)\to (1,-1)} \frac{y+1}{(3(x-1)^2+2(y+1)^2)^{1/3}} \leq \lim_{(x,y)\to (1,-1)} \frac{\lVert[x-1,y+1]\rVert}{(2\lVert[x-1,y+1]\rVert ^2+2\lVert[x-1,y+1]\rVert^2)^{1/3}}$

I don't understand why this is true. I know for a fact that $(y+1) \leq ||[x-1,y+1]||$ but I don't understand what's going on in the denominator. As far as I know the denominator of the first function should be greater than or equal to the one on the second function for this inequality to hold true, but I don't understand why it works here.

Edit: $\lVert [x-1,y+1] \rVert^2$ is equal to $\sqrt {(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2} $

Comment: What is $||(x-1),(y+1)||$?

Comment: The right hand side  is the sum of two identical terms?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz Oh sorry it is the norm of the vector. I already edited my notation to the one in MathJax.

Comment: @Bernard Yes it is, I guess it is written that way to make it more understandable, as in one of those is related to 3(x-1)^2 and the other one to 2(y+1)^2. In the next step he adds them up and ends up with 4||(x-1),(y+1)||^2

Comment: @Direwolfox do you mean a vector with entries $[x-1,y+1]$?

Comment: @mathreadler Yes, so ||(x-1),(y+1)|| means $ \sqrt {(x-1)^2+(y+1)^2}$

Comment: Ok a more common way to write is to enclose the vector $(a,b)$ or $[a,b]$ if it has entries $a$ and $b$, like $\|[x-1,y+1]\|$. It is easier to see first and last element of vector then.

Comment: @mathreadler Oh ok, will do!